# No graphical interface after hard shutdown

Tags: login, password-recovery

I just installed ubuntu on my laptop and I must have spelled my username and or password wrong because I cannot login now.  I tried shuting down my computer manually by holding down the power button and now all I see is a blinking dash.  What can I do?

Comment: More info is needed. Though blinking cursor means at booting time? If thats the case have you checked BIOS for boot priority? or if blinking cursor is at login time?

Comment: you may now have a corrupted installation - why don't you reinstall?  should just take a few minutes.

Comment: For future reference - the 11.04 login screen has a shutdown button on the bottom right hand corner.

Answer (score 1):

You can reinstall. Or the geeky method would be this:

- Boot from the live CD into Ubuntu.
- Mount your hard drive by opening it in Nautilus/Dolphin
- Open a terminal window
- type `cd /media` to go where the harddrives are
- type `ls` to see the names of all of them. One is your root drive.
- become root by doing `sudo su`, the password is empty, just press enter
- `chroot HARD_DRIVE_NAME`
- `passwd YOUR_SHORT_USER_NAME` and enter a new password
- reboot and use your new password